# Use oc rsh to run for loop in container (openshift remote ssh)?

Tags: openshift, rsh

Based on:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/remote-for-loop-over-ssh

I am trying to run a for loop command through `oc rsh` but it fails with below error:

```
$ oc rsh my-app-10-lprki 'for i in /var/lib/*; do echo $i; done'
exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"for i in /var/lib/*; do echo $i; done\": stat for i in /var/lib/*; do echo $i; done: no such file or directory"
command terminated with exit code 1
```

I have also tried without quotes, with double quotes but that also fails.

This works fine (without quotes):

```
$ oc rsh my-app-10-lprki ls -la /var/lib/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x.  1 root       root   104 Nov 22 22:21 .
drwxr-xr-x.  1 root       root    17 Sep 28  2017 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root       root    44 Sep 28  2017 alternatives
```

Any suggestions on how to run a for loop remotely through `oc rsh` like (that currently fails):

```
oc rsh my-app-10-lprki 'for i in /var/lib/*; do echo $i; done'
```

?

Based on below suggestions I have also tried:

```
$ oc rsh my-app-10-lprki -- /bin/sh  -c  'for i in `ls  /var/lib`; do echo $i; done'
exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"--\": executable file not found in $PATH"
command terminated with exit code 1
```

and:

```
$ oc rsh my-app-10-lprki -- /bin/bash  -c  'for i in `ls  /var/lib`; do echo $i; done'
exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"--\": executable file not found in $PATH"
command terminated with exit code 1
```

and:

```
$ oc rsh my-app-10-lprki -- /usr/bin/bash  -c  'for i in `ls  /var/lib`; do echo $i; done'
exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"--\": executable file not found in $PATH"
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Where:

```
$ oc rsh my-app-10-lprki which bash
/usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: Hi, can you try with `oc rsh  my-app-10-lprki  -- bash  -c  "for i in /var/lib/*; do echo $i; done"`

Comment: That gives: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"--\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: use `/bin/bash or /bin/sh` instead of `bash` depending on the shell in your container.

Comment: Can you describe your pod `oc describe pod $POD_NAME` assuming that its running

Comment: Are you executing the command from windows ?

Answer (score 4):

This did the trick:

```
oc exec my-app-10-lprki -- bash -c 'for i in /var/lib/; do echo $i; done'
```

Comment: glad, it worked. quite strange that it does not work with `rsh`.  could be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `/bin/sh`  the shell in your container

```
oc rsh my-app-10-lprki -- /bin/sh  -c  'for i in `ls  /var/lib`; do echo $i; done'
```

will list out the  files in `/var/lib` directory

here is the example of **mysql** pod

```
[suresh.vishnoi@blah ~]$ oc exec  mysql-4-lnlpx --  /bin/sh  -c  'for i in `ls  /var/lib`; do echo $i; done'
alternatives
dbus
games
initramfs
machines
misc
mysql
rhsm
rpm
rpm-state
selinux
systemd
yum
```

Comment: Can you rsh into the pod and run `echo "$SHELL"` or `which sh` or `which bash` ?

Comment: Yes I did that see my updated post. But looks like it works when using exec instead and with slightly different parameters